# Custom function inside a Django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

How do I calculate the total with the existing model fields

```
class Book(models.Model):
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=None, 
unique=True)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    bundle = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    particulars = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tax_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    tax_CGST = models.FloatField(default=0)
    tax_SGST = models.FloatField(default=0)
    total = models.FloatField()

    def total(self):
        return ((self.tax_SGST+self.tax_CGST)*self.amount)/100

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the above code, I want the total function to calculate the total from the Tax and amount fields and add it to the total field in the database

Comment: When do you want this to happen? On save? Will the total figure replace what was in the total field or ADD to the figure?

Comment: I want the user to just give amount and tax, so yea On save